# Datastax recommended approach for session and connection

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

We are using Datastax Graph database. We are creating a bean for graphtraversalSource like,

```
@Bean
GraphTraversalSource graphTraversalSource() {
    DseCluster.Builder dseBuilder = DseCluster.builder();
    dseBuilder.addContactPoints(contactPoints);
    dseBuilder.withGraphOptions(new GraphOptions().setGraphName(dseGraph));
    DseSession dseSession = dseBuilder.build().connect();
    return DseGraph.traversal(dseSession);
  }
```

The GraphTraversalSource is injected in our repository layer. DseSession is re-used for all our queries. we are seeing a performance impact, each query takes 2 seconds to execute.

We want to understand whether should we have to handle session connection and close ? or should we have to create GraphTraversalSource for each query?

is GraphTraversalSource stateless?

Comment: Are you sure that DseCluster & DseSession are reused? Establishing the connection is very heavyweight operation, and session and cluster should be shared between sessions - from your code I see that they are created for every traversal

Comment: GraphTraversalSource is created a bean and injected in repository layer. My Question is should GraphTraversalSource be created as a singleton?

Comment: I believe that GraphTraversal isn't stateless...

Comment: @AlexOtt : The question is more of is `GraphTraversalSource` thread-safe ? Atleast per this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/Rkw6gxTDsxE) it is supposed to be and meant to be re-used. What would be datastax's recommendation on means to get a GraphTraversalSource that is remote connected to a DSE cluster and is meant to be used inside a highly concurrent app. Today our code creates only one instance of GraphTraversalSource for the entire app's lifecycle and we are seeing not so good response times.

Comment: DSE Graph is highly dependent on use case design and modeling in terms of performance. Please update your question and include your use case and end data model as well as what problem you're trying to solve. DSE graph is not always the answer.

Comment: That mailing list thread is correct - you should re-use your `GraphTraversalSource`. If performance is not what you expect then you might want to ask a question about the nature of your traversal that is "slow".